# pandas group by three day or two week or four month for timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a pandas beginner. i want to three day or two week or four month

I have the following data:

```
a = [{"content": '11', "time": 1577870427}, 
     {"content": '44', "time": 1577870427},
     {"content": '22', "time": 1578043227},
     {"content": '33', "time": 1578129627}, 
     {"content": '44', "time": 1578216027},
     {"content": '55', "time": 1578302427}, 
     {"content": '66', "time": 1577956827}]
```

And I want:

```
2020-01-01: [
     {"content": '11', "time": '2020-01-01'},
     {"content": '44', "time": '2020-01-01'},
     {"content": '22', "time": '2020-01-02'},
    ]

 2020-01-03: [
     {"content": '33', "time": '2020-01-03'}, 
     {"content": '44', "time": '2020-01-04'},
    ]

2020-01-05: [
     {"content": '55', "time": '2020-01-05'}, 
     {"content": '66', "time": '2020-01-06'}
    ]
```

my code

```
index = pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in a], unit='s')
df = pd.Series(a,index)

d1 = {k: v.to_dict('r') for k, v in df.groupby('2d')}
print(d1)
```

Comment: And what is the logic behind what you want? What have you tried? Please share some explanation regarding how to achieve the desired output and where did you fail in your attempts.

Comment: @ Celius Stingher  i use groupby('2d') raise error

Comment: @xin.chen - add your solution to question, is no problem if not working.

Comment: @ jezrael  i update question  ，please tell me truth code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert values to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
#convert column to datetimes
d = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
#change format of datetimes
df['time'] = d.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#create DatetimeIndex
df.index = d

#create nested dictionaries
d = {k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'): v.to_dict('r') for k, v in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2D'))}
```

Or:

```
d = {k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'): v.to_dict('r') for k, v in df.resample('2D')}
```

---

```
print (d)
{'2020-01-01': [{'content': '11', 'time': '2020-01-01'}, 
                {'content': '44', 'time': '2020-01-01'}, 
                {'content': '66', 'time': '2020-01-02'}], 
'2020-01-03': [{'content': '22', 'time': '2020-01-03'}, 
               {'content': '33', 'time': '2020-01-04'}], 
 '2020-01-05': [{'content': '44', 'time': '2020-01-05'}, 
                {'content': '55', 'time': '2020-01-06'}]}
```

Comment: @xin.chen - Do you think `s = pd.Series(a)` ?